# how to dynamically update html table in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

how to dynamically update search content under the hostname column in HTML table.
the search content needs to be updated every time and the row number should increase accordingly on the basis of number of hostname entered by the user.

this is my index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    
    
    
    {% block title %} IP Finder {% endblock %}
    
    
    {% block body %}

<body>
<div>

        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group">

            <label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Enter website" autocomplete="off">
            </label>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
</div>

<div>
<div id="section2">
<center>
<table class = "a">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>IP Address(IPv4)</th>
    <th>IP Address(IPv6)</th>
    <th>Port 1</th>
    <th>Port 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{{ hostname }}</td>
    <td>{{ ipv4 }}</td>
    <td>{{ ipv6 }}</td>
    <td>{{ port1 }}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import dns
import dns.resolver
import socket
import sys


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        search = request.POST.get('search')
        # search = 'www.google.com'
        # search = "'" + search + "'"
        ip_address = dns.resolver.Resolver()
        IPv4 = ip_address.resolve(search, 'A').rrset[0].to_text()
        IPv6 = ip_address.resolve(search, 'AAAA').rrset[0].to_text()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {"ipv4": IPv4, "ipv6": IPv6, "hostname": search})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either 1) Implement Ajax 2) Or preload all of the tables data and then use Datatables.net [0] to implement dynamic search.

[0] https://datatables.net/

Comment: thanks for the help. I want to update the hostname column with what user has entered . I am new to the web development platform and I do not know how to implement ajax code could you help me with the same/